# Keep user logged-In after username change

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

Am using passport js for authenticating my users, but i have a problem with the change of username in the dashboard, whenever a user change his/her username and click on the update button, they are automatically logged out and redirected to login page. Is there any way they can be still authenticated after updating their username without making a login again. The ones I tried returned Bad request.

```
router.put("/dashboard/:id/update", isLoggedIn, isVerified, function(req,res){
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.updated, function(error, updated){
        if(error){
            console.log("error occured " + error);
            return res.redirect("/dashboard")
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                res.redirect("/dashboard/" + req.params.id + "/view")
            });

        }
    })
})
```

Middle Ware

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    req.flash("error", "Please login first to do that")
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: is `console.log("error occured " + error);` get executed ?

Comment: No the error is not executed @HamzaFatmi

Comment: so it must be in the middlewares, can you show the code of `isLoggedIn` ?, btw when they log in again , the username is updated ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the isLoggedIn middleware @HamzaFatmi